# Evaluating Checkboxes in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I created several checkboxes like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model,'rememberMe')->checkBox() ?>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to evaluate, whether Checkbox has been checked, or not. Following code:

```
if ($model->rememberMe ==1) echo "Checkbox is activated";
else echo "Checkbox is not activated";
```

**always** prints out 'Checkbox is not activated'. Any ideas, how to fix that?

Comment: And where is placed this `if` statement?

Comment: Provide more code. In controller you must load form data to model, then you can check "rememberMe" attribute. Ready to use example is in https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic

Comment: Do you [load](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail) the data into the model?

Comment: in yii2's application template, you can check SiteController, actionLogin, respectively models, LoginForm, function login to see how yii is handling attribute "rememberMe" (type boolean, rendered via checkbox)